# How to shutdown Sinatra web app programmatically?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I start it like this:

```
require 'sinatra/base'
class App < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    'Hello, world!'
  end
end
App.run!
```

And it runs. Now I want to shut it down from another thread. How can I do that?

```
Thread.new do
  if it_is_time_to_finish
    # How?
  end
end
```

Comment: `App.quit!` ? https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1436

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk indeed. Make it an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to [this line](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1436) you can use `App.quit!` or its alias `App.stop!`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both `App.quit!` or `App.stop!`.